# Is there a way to reverse animations in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, scene

I'm currently learning so excuse my ignorance. Is there a way to reverse an animation in Swift? I have a function that has some basic animations within a SCNTransaction and I have a button that activates that animation.

```
func displayAnimation() {
        if let displayAnimationNode = sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "display", recursively: true) {

            SCNTransaction.begin()
            displayAnimationNode.position.y = 3
            displayAnimationNode.eulerAngles.z = -2
            SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 2.5
            SCNTransaction.commit()
        }
    }
```

I have looked through the documentation but there doesn't seem to be a .reversed method. How can I make this animation just as smooth but in reverse?

Comment: Check out this article https://medium.freecodecamp.org/interactive-animations-with-swifts-uiviewpropertyanimator-284262530a0a

Comment: Better to use [SCNAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnaction) for animation and get `reversed` method to apply reverse action.

Answer (score 2):

Use SCNAction to add reverse animation.

```
let moveY = SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 3, z: 0, duration: 2.5)
let moveZ = SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 0, z: -2, duration: 2.5)
let moveYZ = SCNAction.sequence([moveY, moveZ])

// You can use group to simultaneously perform animation
// let rotateAndHover = SCNAction.group([moveY, moveZ])

// This line of code will reverse your animation
moveYZ.reversed()    

let repeatForever = SCNAction.repeatForever(moveXZ)

runAction(repeatForever)
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hey Mayur, thanks for your reply. however, the animation do not work.                    func displayAnimation() {
        if let displayAnimationNode = sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "display", recursively: true) {
            let displayMove = SCNAction.move(by: SCNVector3(0, 3, -2), duration: 2.5)
             }    Nothing happens.